# PHPMyAdmin - Wordpress XML export fails to import

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a Wordpress PHPMyAdmin `XML` export back into PHPMyAdmin.

**Structure**

```
<pma_xml_export version="1.0" xmlns:pma="https://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/">
    <!--
    - Structure schemas
    -->
    <pma:structure_schemas>
...
```

**Resembles in PHPMyAdmin error**

[image: PHPMYAdmin import error]

How can I import the Wordpress `XML` export?

Without the need to manually provide some XML parsing logic to strip the SQL statements.

Comment: You could look at XML > SQL converters?

Answer (score 0):

Why you use the XML format over SQL or gz or tar.gz formats?

Comment: Next time you can use the 'comment' below the question to signal these thoughts - it's not really an 'answer' ... to answer your remark : I'm dependent on the files i've received from third-party. They are not able to provide me with a .sql / ...

Comment: Thank you for your notice about commenting. I 'm new to the community, so I apologize for this mistake.

Comment: Regarding your situation: it is weird that they can't provide the sql format of exported database, by the way I'm looking into it, as soon as finding the solution, I will notify you here.